# cannot create directory ‘/proc/sys/net/bridge’: No such file or directory

Tags: kubernetes

I want to install kubernetes on centos 7. I have installed kubeadm and use kubeadm to install kubernetes. `kubeadm init`
error:

```
error execution phase preflight: [preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
        [ERROR FileContent--proc-sys-net-bridge-bridge-nf-call-iptables]: /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables does not exist
        [ERROR SystemVerification]: failed to parse kernel config: unable to load kernel module: "configs", output: "", err: exit status 1
        [ERROR SystemVerification]: unsupported graph driver: vfs
[preflight] If you know what you are doing, you can make a check non-fatal with `--ignore-preflight-errors=...`
```

then I run the command `mkdir /proc/sys/net/bridge` and get error `mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/proc/sys/net/bridge’: No such file or directory`.
How to fix it?

Comment: are you trying sudo kubeadm init?

Comment: yes, try sudo kubeadm init, same error.

Comment: you install the kubernetes in a virtual machine?

Comment: Try `sysctl -w net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=1` and let me know if it works.

Comment: @HelloWorld I am sorry to tell you that failed with error `sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables: No such file or directory`. Maybe I need to recover my machine.

Comment: Run `modprobe br_netfilter` for this dir to appear. Also `mkdir /proc/sys/net/bridge` wouldn't work because `/proc` dir is a virtual file system (it's faked be the linux).